# Is there any function(or method, whatever) in SDL2 that act like std::cin or getline?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm working on a game, and there's a part that the player needs to enter a word in order to progress,and my game used the SDL2 library,so I need a function that accepts the player's input( like std::cin or getline.

Comment: SDL2 does not support the display of text by default iirc. SDL2 is a light weight library. To support the input / display of user generated text you'll most likely have to include an other library build on top of SDL2.